# azcopy metadata with a value that has a semicolon

Tags: escaping, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

This is probably a simple question but for some reason I can't find the answer
I'm trying to upload a file to our blob storage and in the process setting the metadata properly for reading it afterwards.

So currently I have the following command:
`azcopy copy "<local file path>" "<blob file path>?<sas token>" --metadata "demo=2;5"`
this doesn't work and it's because of the semicolon
`azcopy copy "<local file path>" "<blob file path>?<sas token>" --metadata "demo=25"`
this however works but beats the purpose of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. I looked up the source code for [`azcopy`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/blob/master/ste/mgr-JobPartMgr.go#L316) and it is using `;` as the delimiter to separate multiple metadata key/value pairs.

```
metadataString := string(dstData.Metadata[:dstData.MetadataLength])
jpm.metadata = common.Metadata{}
if len(metadataString) > 0 {
    for _, keyAndValue := range strings.Split(metadataString, ";") { // key/value pairs are separated by ';'
        kv := strings.Split(keyAndValue, "=") // key/value are separated by '='
        jpm.metadata[kv[0]] = kv[1]
    }
}
```

You may want to open up an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues and let the team know about the problem.

Comment: Seems like your right, I'll create the issue thanks for pointing this one out.